# GAS Script Date Manipulation

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to add 7 days to the current date and name a sheet with that value. Below is the code I would think would work, but it keeps the date format and adds the 7 days to the year rather than the day.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), tz, 'MM-dd-yy');
var day1 = date +7
sheets[1].setName(day1);  // Rename second
```

Do I have something incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

Use setDate JavaScript method.

## Explanation

Google Apps Script use JavaScript to handle date objects, so you should use JavaScript methods instead of typical Google Sheets methods.

By the other hand, Utilities.formatDate() returns a string, not a date object.

The following script set the name of the second sheet as the date of seven days from now:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tz = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var date = new Date();
  var nextDate = new Date();
  var days = 7;
  nextDate.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
  var stringDate = Utilities.formatDate(nextDate, tz, 'MM-dd-yy');
  ss.getSheets()[1].setName(stringDate)
}
```

## References

[Add days to JavaScript Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/563406/1595451)